# R, using table function on a list

Tags: r, list

If I define a list like this:

```
a <- list(1,2,3,4,5,1)
```

and then call `table(a)` , I get:

```
, , a.3 = 3, a.4 = 4, a.5 = 5, a.6 = 1

   a.2
a.1 2
  1 1
```

Isn't this behavior weird? How could I use the table function on this list to get something like:

```
1 2 3 4 5 
2 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: `table(unlist(a))`? Is there a reason it needs to remain a `list`?

Comment: @r2evans. I'm new to R and I could not find the answer by googling it, so I posted this question here! Thanks for your simple solution. Is my question a duplicate on this site?

Comment: I haven't seen it before, but that doesn't mean anything. It is likely a fairly basic question, but perhaps not so basic when you are learning it from scratch.

Comment: @r2evans Would you please add your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `table` function provides *"a contingency table of the counts at each combination of factor levels"* (from [`?table`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/table.html)). Since it works on *vectors* and not a `list`, you just need to unlist it:

```
unlist(a)
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 1
table(unlist(a))
# 1 2 3 4 5 
# 2 1 1 1 1
```